# Straight lines on surfaces other than $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, noneuclidean-geometry

Let  $\mathbb{S}^{2}$  be
$$\mathbb{S}^{2}:=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{matrix}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^3\middle| x^2+y^2+z^2=1\right\}$$
,and let $\mathbb{H}$ be
$$\mathbb{H}:=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{matrix}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^3\middle| x^2+y^2-z^2=-1 ,z > 0 \right\}$$

Here, the $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a three dimensional Euclidean space, and the $\textbf{O}$ means the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Then, according to [my text book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4595315767) , following very beautiful theorems are satisfied on both $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$.
On the other hand, there are various curved surfaces other than the spherical surface and the (upper side of) biplane hyperboloid; for example, one-leaf hyperboloid, paraboloid, torus, projective plane, Mobius ring, etc.

> **【My Question】**
> (1) What are some other surfaces other than $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}$ that have the following theorem?
> (2) In particular, is it possible to "define" a straight line in other surfaces in a way similar to the following theorem? For example, one-leaf hyperboloid, paraboloid, torus, projective plane, Mobius ring.
> (3) If possible, How is that?

> **【Theorem 1】**
> The straight line on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ shall be the intersection of "$\mathbb{S}^{2}$" and "the plane through the $\textbf{O}$".
> The intersection of "$\mathbb{S}^{2}$" and "the plane through the $\textbf{O}$" shall be the straight line on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$.

> **【Theorem 2】**
> The straight line on $\mathbb{H}$ shall be the intersection of "$\mathbb{H}$" and  "the plane through the $\textbf{O}$".
> The intersection of "$\mathbb{H}$" and "the plane through the $\textbf{O}$" shall be the straight line on $\mathbb{H}$.(See the following Fig.1.)

Here, the planes on Th1 and Th2 are the plane in the sense of Euclidean space.

[image]
Fig.1 is quoted from [this site](http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/jp3_poinc.htm) with some modifications, representing the relationship between "the line on $\mathbb{H}$" and "the plane through the $\textbf{O}$.

Comment: You have the only two types where it works for all intersections. If you have a surface of revolution, say an ellipsoid around the z axis, then the intersection with the xy plane (the equator) is a geodesic, so are all the intersections with planes containing the z axis, often called meridians or lines of longitude.... Just as other plane intersections with the sphere give circles that are not great circles, intersections of other planes with the hyperboloid give geodesic circles, horocycles, and constant distance curves.

Comment: You have a misinterpretation here, I believe. I believe that $\mathbb H$ is meant to be (one model of) the hyperbolic plane (i.e., constant negative curvature). In order to obtain that from the hyperboloid, you need to work in Lorentz space, not in Euclidean $\Bbb R^3$. The hyperboloid as it sits in $\Bbb R^3$ has very different geodesics ("lines").

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thank you for your comment. You think Th2 isn't right?　Indeed, there is no proof of Th2 in my textbook. However, the theorem seemed plausible from the geometric intuition as shown in Figure 1.

Comment: Your edit establishes that I am correct. They're showing the usual correspondence between the hyperboloid in Lorentz space (which to the naked eye looks like the hyperboloid in Euclidean space, but the geometry is totally different) and the Klein model of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Th 2 *is* correct, but the geometry on the hyperboloid, as I say, is inherited from the Lorentz metric in $3$-space, not the Euclidean metric. The geodesics ("lines") on the Euclidean hyperboloid of two sheets are totally different (indeed, the only unbounded ones are the meridians — and those are obtained by slicing with a vertical plane through the origin). It might be safer to stick with the Klein disc model of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: If you're interested in pursuing this study, get a differential geometry text (e.g., my own, freely downloadable from the link in my profile) and read about the Clairaut relation, which geometrically characterizes geodesics on surfaces of revolution in Euclidean $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin  Does that mean that the H such that Th2 is viable is not embedded in R^3? (Riemannian manifolds with a different metric than the one derived from R^3 and put into the set H is the H of the Th2?)

Comment: That's correct. Hilbert proved over a century ago that there is no complete surface of constant negative curvature in $\Bbb R^3$. The letter $\Bbb H$ should *not* be used for the usual hyperboloid of two sheets in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin  Thanks for the comment. Is this the textbook you're referring to? I'm going to try it.  https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf

Comment: That's the only differential geometry text linked there, isn't it? So, yes. :D

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  Generally, the "Calculus, and Manifolds" may a field that includes curvature theory, so I checked it just in case, thank you.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  If I were to add the following statement to Theorem 2, would Th2 be perfectly correct?
"The remanian metric derived from $\left\langle\middle|\right\rangle_{H}$ is included in $\mathbb{H}$; here 
${\left\langle\left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\\\end{matrix}\right)\middle|\left(\begin{matrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2\\\end{matrix}\right)\right\rangle}_H≔{x_1}{x_2}+{y_1}{y_2}-{z_1}{z_2}$"

Comment: No. The restriction of that Lorentzian metric *to* the hyperboloid you've given is a Riemannian metric of constant negative curvature on the hyperboloid. This means we've given a model of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Dark red line on Fig 1 is a straight line on $(\mathbb{H}, \left\langle\middle|\right\rangle_{H})$ but not (always) straight line on    $(\mathbb{H}, \left\langle\middle|\right\rangle)$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. The only time it's a "straight line" (i.e., geodesic) in the Euclidean hyperboloid is when the slicing plane through the origin is *vertical*. I'm not sure if we've converged to what should be considered an *answer* to your question.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Euclidean hyperboloid  you said is $(\mathbb{H}, \left\langle\middle|\right\rangle)$?  And you mean, on the $(\mathbb{H}, \left\langle\middle|\right\rangle_{H})$ , the slicing plane through the origin is not necessarily to  vertical to the x-y plane?

Comment: Blue there does seem to be a pretty good summary on that site. One thing missing, some of the maps commute very nicely when both the Klein disc is placed in the plane $z=1,$ while the Poincare disc is placed at $z=0.$   the relationships can be drawn nicely by hand by taking an intersection with the plane $y=0.$ The two discs are now parallel line segments, the standard 2-sphere becomes the standard unit circle, central projection is around the origin and stereographic projection is around (0,0,-1)

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks for your comment. That site you said is "(http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/jp3_poinc.htm)" ? This site (written in Japanese) certainly has a lot  about hyperbolic surfaces.

Comment: @Will Jagy Regarding your first comment....
There is essentially only H and S2 that satisfy the  "all intersections are straight line ". However, this H is the one with the Minkowski metric. Am I right?

Also, if "some intersections are straight line", there are various examples. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. An instructive example is the staircase minimal surface of Riemann. for a set of parallel planes, all intersections with the surface are circles or lines.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%27s_minimal_surface   I like to include the word staircase, because Riemann surfaces are something completelt different

Comment: @Will Jagy　So, as for the proof that there are essentially no surfaces that fullly satisfy the above theorem other than S2 and H...
Consider the surfaces deffined by zelo set of σx^2 σy^2 σz^2 σ1, here, σ=+ or -.
If only the fourth sigma is -, it is spherical, and if only one of the first three sigmas is -, it is H.
But there are other ways to put the different signs in. Maybe it's important to get x^2+y^2=1 and x^2-y^2=-1 right, though....